# How to select dynamic class in jQuery change function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I have a input field having dynamic class as:

```
<input class="chek" data-id="1" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
<input class="chek" data-id="2" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
<input class="chek" data-id="3" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
```

Here is my Js:

```
$(".chek").unbind().change(function(e) {
var getid = $(this).attr('data-id');
alert(getid);
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
        url: base_url + '/admin/program/setslider?selected='+getid,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: getid,
        headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
       })
```

Problem is `$(this).attr('data-id');` returns all the data-id attr refering to           same class chek (i supposed `$(this)` would return data-id if specific class only but it returns all the data-id)

Solution I suppose is getting dynamic class for selecting specific input like:

```
<input class="chek_1" data-id="1" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
<input class="chek_2" data-id="2" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
<input class="chek_3" data-id="3" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
```

And JS be like:

```
$(".chek_'+ id +'").unbind().change(function(e) {
// code here
 }
```

## Note:

I am using bootstrap toggle http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ to make        change in checkbox.

Comment: Your question is unclear.. On check/uncheck of any checkbox you want to make any operation?

Comment: You will need to be a lot more specific about what your problem is and what you are trying to do. See [ask]

Comment: Thanx  appreciated, see the chang in question.

Comment: When you say "$(this).attr('data-id'); returns all the data-id attr refering to same class chek" - that is absolutely not true. It only gets the one you've changed. See:  https://jsfiddle.net/3tk62zdw/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the change event of the checkboxes.

Based on your HTML you can use the following code to get the change event.

```
$("input[data-toggle='toggle']").change(function(){
      alert(this.checked);
});
```

OR

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
      alert(this.checked);
});
```

Refer [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/74/)

Comment: thanks for instance reply, actually my question was not clear see the change in my question. my problem is selecting specific class for calling change function to specific input

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.. I have created a fiddle based on your code, it is not returning all the data-id's. Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/75/